# Is the row order guaranteed when using a table value constructor?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

In the following T-SQL script:

```
CREATE TABLE #testdata 
    (id int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
     field VARCHAR(MAX))

INSERT INTO #testdata
VALUES
('this should be row 1'),
('this should be row 2'),
('this should be row 3')
```

is there any guarantee that id will match the intended row number?
This seems to be the case in all my tests so far, but I can't find any documentation saying that this is always the case.

I'd like to rely on this behavior, but I need to be sure that there isn't any factor that might result in a different insert order.

I am using SQL Server 2012.

Comment: Since tables have no inherent user-observable ordering guarantees, the most you can seek is a guarantee about the assignment of `IDENTITY` values to rows, which is what the question I've linked to addresses.

Comment: The `identity` ill guarantee each insertion ill receive a sequential number. Later you can fetch the rows ordered by that number.